How to Diagnose and Resolve "The selected scanner could not be found" Error in NAPS2 with EPSON XP-3100 via CMD/PowerShell?
I'm having trouble with my EPSON XP-3100 Series scanner connected via Wi-Fi. When I try to scan a new document using NAPS2, I get the following error:
Error: The selected scanner could not be found

What I've Tried So Far

Ping the Scanner:
ping [Scanner_IP_Address]


Successful replies with no packet loss.


Check Network Configuration:
Get-NetIPConfiguration


Confirmed my computer is on the correct network.


Test Network Connection:
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName [Scanner_IP_Address] -Port 80


Connection test succeeded.


Check Installed Drivers:
Get-PnpDevice -Class Imaging


No imaging devices found.


Add Printer Port:
Add-PrinterPort -Name "IP_[Scanner_IP_Address]" -PrinterHostAddress "[Scanner_IP_Address]"


Add Printer:
Add-Printer -Name "EPSON XP-3100" -DriverName "EPSON XP-3100 Series" -PortName "IP_[Scanner_IP_Address]"


Error: The specified port does not exist.


Check Windows Services:
sc query stisvc


stisvc (Windows Image Acquisition) service is running.


Review NAPS2 Error Logs: removing the scanner and adding a new one



now I get the error:


Error logs indicate an SSL connection issue:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond [fe80::3a1a:52ff:fe3b:67f4]:443



Additional Information

OS: Windows 10
Scanner Model: EPSON XP-3100 Series
Connection Type: Wi-Fi
NAPS2 Version: 7.1.0.0

Question
How can I diagnose and resolve this issue using CMD and/or PowerShell? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

as suggested in the comments I reinstalled the driver and now when selecting "WIA Driver" I get:

Error WIA error code 80080005 with the "Technical Details":

NAPS2.Wia.WiaException: WIA error code 80080005
   at new NAPS2.Wia.WiaDeviceManager(WiaVersion version)
   at async Task<ScanDevice> NAPS2.Scan.ScanPerformer.PromptForDevice(ScanOptions options) x 2
   at async void NAPS2.EtoForms.Ui.EditProfileForm.ChooseDevice(object sender, EventArgs args)



It seems you haven't installed the drivers?...

@ChanganAuto I believe I have because this scanner used to work on this machine before. How can I check via cmd/PowerShell if the drivers are installed properly?

Why don't you just download the up-to-date drivers from Epson and then install it? That guarantees you have the latest version and if already installed that same version you'll see a notification saying exactly that. It's great to use commands and all (I use them everyday in Linux) but also there's nothing wrong in doing the things like the vendors intended for end-users.

@ChanganAuto reinstalled the driver from here and updated the post with the new error.

Weird error... Mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/application-management/error-8008005-when-start-complus-applications but mot sure if related.

OK I am not sure what I did but after installing "EPSON Scan" from the same page as above I selected "TWAIN Driver" and now it works fine. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

@Foad, Think of the device as having two parts: the printer, and the scanner. Printer drivers cover printing, TWAIN drivers are for scanning. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TWAIN : "TWAIN and TWAIN Direct are... [API's] and protocols that regulate communication between software and digital imaging devices, such as image scanners.
